# A simple version of the Picard-Lindelöf Theorem

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, metric-spaces

I wish to ask a particular question about following the proof in this theorem, and thought the best place to come might be here. It is as follows:

First, we have a differential equation that integrates up to be in the form

$x(t)=x_0+\int_{t_0}^t\,f(s,x(s))\,ds$.

We work in the metric space $(X,d)=(C(I_a), d_u)$, where $I_a = [t_0-a,t_0+a]$ and $d_u(x(t),y(t)) = \sup_{t\in I_a}|x(t) - y(t)|$ is the uniform metric. Now define the subspace $A\subset X$ by $A=\{y\in X: y(t)\in I_b\}$ where $I_b=[x_0-b,x_0+b]$.

My question is, how do I show that $A$ is closed? I have attempted a solution, so I will post this and maybe someone can just tell me what I'm missing (if anything):

If $(y_n)$ is some convergent sequence in A, then it converges to some $y$, from which $d_u(y_n,y)\rightarrow 0$ as $n\rightarrow\infty$. Must it then follow that $y\in A$, so that $A$ contains all its limit points and is hence closed? I think so, but feel like I cannot substantiate this claim properly. Any help would be greatly appreciated, and I thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood properly your definition of $A$, we have
$$A= \{ y \in X : y(I_a) \subseteq I_b\}$$

Now, let $y_n \to y$ in $X$, with $\{ y_n\}_n \subset A$. For all $t \in I_a$ and for all $n$, you have
$$x_0-b \le y_n(t) \le x_0+b$$
sending $n \to \infty$ (uniform convergence implies pointwise convergence) you have $$x_0-b \le y(t) \le x_0+b$$
so $y \in A$.

Comment: This would be the step I was missing. Thanks very much.